# How to prevent event OnChange on dojo Select

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am working on localization and use cookie to store language. I have a `Select`:

```
var select = new dijit.form.Select({
    name: "languageSelect",
    onChange: function (value) {
        changeLanguage(value);
    }
}, "languageSelect");
```

in `onChange` event, will call method `changeLanguage`:

```
 var changeLanguage = function (language) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/api/accounts/changelanguage?language=" + language,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.reload(false);
        }
    });
};
```

This method with do ajax call to server and then re-load page.

The problem is: on the page load, I need to read cookie `language` which user chose before and set it to `Select`:

```
select.set("value", readCookie("language"));
```

But, this `set` causes the event `OnChange` fire, then make page re-load which I don't want at the beginning. I tried to use one flag like below but it does not work out:

```
var select = new dijit.form.Select({
    name: "languageSelect",
    style: { width: '200px' },
    onChange: function (value) {
        if (isLoading == false)
            changeLanguage(value);
    }
}, "languageSelect");

var isLoading = true;
select.set("value", readCookie("language"));
isLoading = false;
```

Is there anyway to sort it out, I was thinking to prevent event `OnChange` fire on `set` method, but have not found out how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try adding `false`, like:

```
select.set("value", readCookie("language"));
```

to

```
select.set("value", readCookie("language"), false);
```

`false` flag at the end of the `set()` method that will prevent the `onChange` event.

Comment: I had this issue with `dijit/InlineEditBox` and had to monkey patch it. Likewise, if it's not working for you, it's likely you're dealing with a middleman that's throwing away your third parameter. The contract is explicitly `set: function(name, value)`--the third parameter only works by... accident... so it's easy for custom setter code to lose that third param.